# Creating dynamic sql with tsql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
select (select code from SC_StockItem where StockItemID = a.StockItemID)
from SC_StockItemVariantSetAttribValue a
inner join SC_StockItemVariantSetAttribValue a2 on a.StockItemID = a2.StockItemID
and a2.VariantSetAttribValueID = 18
inner join SC_StockItemVariantSetAttribValue a3 on a2.StockItemID = a3.StockItemID
and a3.VariantSetAttribValueID = 12
where a.VariantSetAttribValueID = 26
```

I wish to perform the query above. the lines similar to:

```
inner join SC_StockItemVariantSetAttribValue a2 on a.StockItemID = a2.StockItemID
    and a2.VariantSetAttribValueID = 18
```

will be added accordingly to the number of rows returned from another query. Is there a way I can add these lines in a TSQL function?

Comment: Didn't dynamic-sql fit?

Comment: This is to be used in another function and since it is already a bit demanding on the server I'd prefer if I can avoid multiple calls from c# to sql server

Comment: Best info for dynamic SQL: [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). This should answer everything about dynamic SQL (one of the few ressources that are better than SO ;-)). But how does your other query look? Maybe it is easier to combine the two queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add condition to `join` making this part fixed, not dinamic:

```
inner join SC_StockItemVariantSetAttribValue a2 on (a.StockItemID=a2.StockItemID
and a2.VariantSetAttribValueID = 19 
and @anotherQueryCount > 0)  --here you check your additional rule
```

Join will work if condition is true.